# MySQL NDB Cluster : Disable Replication for a table / database

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

In our project we are planning to introduce MySQL NDB cluster to have 99% uptime for our multiple applications dependent on MySQL.

So MySQL is being deployed in two machines. In both the machines Data Node, Management Server and SQL node is deployed and configured to form a cluster as shown in the below snippet.

Based on my understanding replication of data will be done for the data stored in Data Nodes. But can we restrict the replication only to a set of tables or database?

Reason for this query is, there are two applications that are dependent on MySQL, where only one application needs this replication and the other doesn't need this feature because it should connect to a standalone instance of MySQL to store it's local data which shouldn't be replicated as it would cause problem to the application running in another machine.

Please share your thoughts on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though we have deployed MySQL NDB Cluster, the mysqld still supports INNODB storage type. So in order to achieve the above requested need, we created tables explicitly with Storage Engine by mentioning in CREATE TABLE statement like below. This overrode the storage configuration mentioned in my.cnf.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CDS` (
  `CD_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CD_ID`)
) ENGINE=innodb
```